Magento Setup Using Valet on MacBookPro (redirected you too many times.) error getting
I am doing the project setup using the valet on macbook pro but after all the things done
when i load the url it is showing as below
 This page isn’t working dev.local.test redirected you too many times.
 Try deleting your cookies.
  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

already check the cookie / adminhtml url and also checked the .htaccess file permission
php - 8.1
mac - sillion chip
cd Sites ---> valet park
valet link domain.name --secure
valet paths
valet links
all are tested
